# ruby connect to oracle using kerberos

Tags: ruby, oracle, kerberos

Since Oracle has built in support for kerberos and sqlplus can connect to database using
kerberos using oci8 can i do something similar in ruby like this ?

```
require 'oci8'
oci = OCI8.new('SomeUser','SomePass','hostname.servicename')
oci.exec('select * from table') do |record|
  puts record.join(',')
end
```

can i have a blank username and password ?
and will the connection be sucessful ?
am i on the right path ?

Comment: What is actually your problem/question? Do you want to know how to connect to an Oracle database with Kerberos or to a directory server via LDAP?

Comment: Michael thanks for taking a look yes my question is how to connect to an Oracle Database via kerberos using Ruby and Ruby on Rails

Comment: Please remove the LDAP stuff, it is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, Ruby/RoR is compiled against OCI, since Oracle Call Interface and Net Services Support Kerberos authentication this is possible. Although I cannot tell whether there might be some limitation in Ruby's interface.

First of all, you need to get it working with `SQL*Plus`, after that try your application.
Begin with [Configuring Kerberos Authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10746/asokerb.htm#ASOAG060).

If Ruby OCI8 is implemented correctly, this should do it:

```
OCI8.new(nil, nil, 'net_service_name')
```

or

```
OCI8.new('/@net_service_name')
```